# Territory Management and My Team reporting

Tags: teams

Does enabling Territory Management have any effect on the "My Teams" reporting?  We have some sales reps who report to more than one manager, so a "My Teams" report does not always work for certain managers because the sales rep can only be in one role in the Role Hierarchy. I'm not clear on how Territory Management might help with this problem, or if it does at all?  In other words...would a My Teams type of report still be based on the Role Hierarchy even if we implement territory management?

Answer (score 0):

You will still have the "my teams" option on reports but it shows your team with the role hierarchy, and an additional optiom will be added for "my territory"  with your the territory users. On your tabs will have my teams accounts and opps based on the account and opp team with "my territory" accounts and "my territory" opps showing the records in your territory.